# How to dry a champagne glass?

Tags: glass, drinks

How to properly dry a champagne glass like this one:

[image]

The problem is that I can't place them in my washing machine because they get damaged sometimes by the machine. I can't fit my hand in it as well to dry it and folding my towel and trying to twist it in, leaves some stripes which results in the fact that my glass is still not clean. Sometimes the glass even breaks when I use my towel to twist it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rinsing as well as possible, do a final rinse with distilled or deionoized water, then hang or rack the glass upside down to dry (preferably in a low-dust location).  If you do the rinse correctly, there should be no dissolved solids left to leave spots on the glass, and no need to stick something inside the fragile flute.

Comment: tnx I didn't want to put anything in the glass and it really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

I use a dry micro-fibre cloth [I do for many things]
Use the 'fluffy' ones you can get from the supermarket - very cheap, two for a pound/dollar/euro these days.

I find them generally small enough to be able to wind into the flute - I've never broken one, ever, this way.
Do the outside first & dry your other hand, for best results.

Also, if you're washing them in regular warm/hot water & washing-up detergent, then don't rinse them. They come out streak-free if you leave them to drain upside down for only 5 minutes [not until completely dry] then wipe over with the micro-fibre, so that it's the micro-fibre that finishes off the drying process.
If you rinse them in anything other than very pure water & leave them to dry naturally, they'll streak.

Answer (score 0):

After wash, you could use table tissue paper to remove existing water droplets if any. You could also dry the glass using [flour sack](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003LJY990).

- Place the wine glass upside down on a soft towel so that it can air dry.
- Dry the glasses with a soft, lint-free towel if you live in an area that has hard water.